# Filter duplicate rows in Hive: Count unique IDs that occur for only one category

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with IDs and two categories. The IDs can be unique to a category or can belong to both categories. I want to count just the IDs that are unique to either category.

```
ID CATEGORY
1    A
2    A
3    B
2    B
3    B
```

In the above example, I want to return IDs 1 and 3 but not 2. I tried using a subquery but they don't seem to be allowed in Hive.

Example output:

```
category unique_occurrences
A         1
B         1
```

I think something like this would work in MS SQL Server:

```
select count(distinct t.ID) AS unique_occurrences, t.category
from table_1 t
where t.id not in (SELECT t2.id 
                   FROM table_1 t2
                   WHERE t.id = t2.id AND t.category != t2.category)
```

But I can't get it to work in Hive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(category) = min(category);
```

Your question seems to suggest that you want to actually delete the rows from the table.  However, the example suggests that you merely want to run a query to get the "pure" ids.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I made some edits to the question now which might make it easier to understand. category is a string in this case so not sure I can use max and min on it?

Comment: Actually, I just tried this and it works. Thanks Gordon. I have to admit I don't totally understand why.